# Python: Can't replace item inside list due to: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, typeerror

I am trying to make a code where I check for a certain item in a list and replace all instances of that item with the human input. I am new to python and am trying to make a function that will work similarly to this

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"]

print(fruits)

findFruit = input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = input("Replace: ")

for findFruit in fruits:
    fruits[findFruit] = [replaceFruit]
    print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you need the index to be able to replace an element from list with a loop
- don't name the iteration parameter `findFruit` that is already your variable

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"]
findFruit = "Banana"  # input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = "Kiwi"  # input("Replace: ")

for idx, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    if fruit == findFruit:
        fruits[idx] = replaceFruit
```

With a list-comprehension

```
fruits = [fruit if fruit != findFruit else replaceFruit for fruit in fruits]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the list index of the item in order to `insert` or remove (`pop`)the item

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"]

findFruit = input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = input("Replace: ")

for i in range(len(fruits)):
    if fruits[i] == findFruit:
        fruits.pop(i)
        fruits.insert(i, replaceFruit)
print(fruits)
```

Output

```
Fruit:  Apple
Replace:  Orange
['Banana', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try this it will replace all matching fruits:

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"]
print(fruits)

findFruit = input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = input("Replace: ")

for i in range(len(fruits)):
    if fruits[i]==findFruit:
        fruits[i] = replaceFruit
print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stay somewhat close to your original example.
*(Be aware, that this solution will only replace the first occurrence of findFruit.)*

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"]

print(fruits)

findFruit = input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = input("Replace: ")

try:
    positionToReplace = fruits.index(findFruit)
except:
    positionToReplace = -1

if positionToReplace >= 0:
    fruits[positionToReplace] = replaceFruit

print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` is what you are looking for. It basically mentions the elements one by one. The `enumerate()` method adds counter to an iterable and returns it (the enumerate object).

```
fruits = ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"]

print(fruits)

findFruit = input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = input("Replace: ")

for idx, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    if fruit == findFruit:
        fruits[idx] = replaceFruit
```